# Excel 2010: How do I reference a specific field using a defined column name and a row number?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, named-ranges

I'm using Excel 2010 and am creating a workbook to define details about products in a store (including category, price, accessories). I also want to define default category details to use if the specific details of a product are left blank.

I set up three sheets: Products, CategoryDefaults, and Calculated.
Columns are the product/category details and each item /category has its own row.
I would also like to use named columns as much as possible for readability. A column name starting with P is the Product detail and one starting with D is from the CategoryDefault sheet.

The fields in Calculated look similar to this:

```
=IF(Products!G2="",
INDEX(DPRICE, MATCH(Products!A2, DCAT, 0)),
Products!G2)
```

where DPRICE is a named column for default pricing and DCAT is the category name for the CategoryDefaults sheet.

The formula means as follows: If Product number 2 Column G is blank, then find the value of Column A Product 2 in the CategoryDefault sheet and return the DefaultPrice. Else return the defined Price.

So far this all works fine. I would like to take it just one step further:
In the previous example Products!G2 refers to the price column for product in row 2. I would like to make to formula more readable by replacing the Column letter reference 'G' with a named column reference, namely 'PPRICE'.
I would do the same with the reference to Products!A2 by calling the column 'PCAT' (the category the product belongs to)

The final formula would look something like this:

```
=IF(Products!PPRICE:2="",
INDEX(DPRICE, MATCH(Products!PCAT:2, DCAT, 0)),
Products!PPRICE:2)
```

I just can't get this to work. I've tried "Apply Names..." with no result and any variation of colons and $ to no avail. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: You provided a good explanation of the setup but it isn't clear what the specific issue is.  Is it just getting names to work (last paragraph), or is there more to the problem?

Comment: The issue is described in the last paragraph. I'll edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `INDEX(PPRICE, 2)` will return the value of the second row in the PPRICE column. The entire code snippet will look like this:

```
=IF(INDEX(PPRICE, 2)="",
INDEX(DPRICE, MATCH(Products!A2, DCAT, 0)),
INDEX(PPRICE, 2))
```

However it will be an absolute value, not a relative value and if you copy paste this formula to other rows it will still point to row 2. This would therefore not be a good idea for large data sets.